# If returns always true

Tags: if-statement

Why does it always return true? Even when i put 'n' in my char choice.

The same thing for my do-while loop.

is there something wrong with my if /do/while fonctions?

```
void LigueHockey::New()

{
    char choice;

    cout << "Entrez l'histoire de la ligue : ";
    getline(cin,histoire);

    cout << "\nQuel est la couleur de la ligue : ";
    getline(cin,couleur);

    cout << "\nEntrez la date d'aujourd'hui(JJ/MM/YYYY) : ";
    cin.getline(creation.jour,sizeof(creation.jour),'/');
    cin.getline(creation.mois,sizeof(creation.mois),'/');
    cin.getline(creation.annee,sizeof(creation.annee));

    cout << "\nEst-ce que le club a gagner un titre? (Y/N) :";
    cin >> choice;
    cin.ignore(); // to skip the endline

    if (choice = 'Y')
    {
        do
        {
            cout << "\nNom de la coupe/titre : ";
            cin.getline(records.coupe,sizeof(records.coupe));
            cout << "\nQuand a-t-il ete remporter? (JJ/MM/YYYY) : ";
            cin.getline(records.dateRemp.jour,sizeof(records.dateRemp.jour),'/');
            cin.getline(records.dateRemp.mois,sizeof(records.dateRemp.mois),'/');
            cin.getline(records.dateRemp.annee,sizeof(records.dateRemp.annee));

            cout << "\nVoulez-vous ajouter un autre coupe/titre? : ";
            cin >> choice;
            cin.ignore();
        }
        while ( choice = 'Y');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (choice = 'Y')` is an assignment, not an equality check. You need `if (choice == 'Y')`

Answer (score 0):

Please use `==` in your if condition
example :

```
if (choice == 'Y')
```

Thanks
Javid